# Example of a convergent pointwise sequence of function and not uniformly convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

- We say that a sequence $f_n(x)$ is **pointwise** convergent to $f(x)$ on the set $E$ when for every $x\in E$ and $\epsilon >0$ there exists an integer $N$ such that  the distance between $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ is smaller than $\epsilon$.
- We say that a sequence $f_n$ is **uniformly** convergent to $f$ on the set $E$  if for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists an integer $N$ such that  the distance between $f_n$ and $f$ is smaller than $\epsilon$.
  The main difference between the aforementioned definitions is that $N$  dependant on $x$ in the context of pointwise convergence, that is for each $x$ in $E$ there exists a specific $N$ associated to $x$ while in the case of uniform convergence there exists a universal $N$ for which the $f_n(x)$  converges to $f(x)$ uniformly with respect to $x$.
  Can you please give me an example of sequence of function that converges pointwise and not unifomly to $f(x)$.
  Thanks in advance

Comment: please see Rudin's principles of mathematical analysis chapter 7